# How could I use the centroid and size of a triangle to find the coordinates of its vertices?

Tags: geometry

I'm making a 3D graphics program in OpenGL and I'm making a function to automatically place the centroid of a triangle on the specified xy coordinates. The triangle will be of a set size. Essentially I need a mathematical equation I can use only having the size and centroid of the triangle to find the xy coordinates of its three vertices.

Comment: What do you mean by size?

Comment: Size as in it is scaled using a certain unit of measurement. To clarify let's say, for example, from one point to a point immediately in its vicinity in any direction it were 1 foot. So each increment of x or y were 1 foot. So if x is 1  then it is 1 foot, if you move over one on the x axis it then becomes 2 feet and so on.

Comment: what do you mean by "from one point to a point immediately in its vicinity in any direction it were one foot".... Points in the vicinity of each other are always 0, are they not??  Perhaps you could provide an image?

Comment: https://edwardseverinsen1717-gmail.tinytake.com/sf/NDg4OTg5XzI2MDA4NzA

Comment: Say I were making an equilateral triangle that was three feet in all directions from the centroid, three would be its size.

Comment: ah,  that makes a lot more sense. I would guess there is a formula for this.  I would rephrase your question as finding the verticies of a triangle given the medians,  which is effectively what you are asking for

Comment: You could use the midpoint formula to get a system of three equations in terms of three variables,  which could be solved used matrices algorithmicly easily

Comment: A triangle can be described by position, size, shape, and orientation. If you want to specify only position and size, you may be stuck with the same shape and orientation for each triangle. In that case, any three vectors that add to zero give the positions of the vertices of a triangle relative to its centroid; multiply the vectors by a scaling factor for "size" and add them to the coordinates of the centroid's position. It's a little unclear how this relates to the "3D" aspect of your program.

Comment: Right now the only coordinates I'm focusing on are x and y because the 3D perspective will come in once I change the camera position and angle but for now I only need a 2D view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centroid and "size" of a triangle don't give you enough information to determine its vertices.

Suppose you have a triangle $T_1$ with centroid at the point $C$. Now rotate $T_1$ around $C$ by some angle to get another triangle $T_2$. The triangles $T_1$ and $T_2$ both have the same size (whatever that means) and the same centroid, but they don't have the same vertices.

We could make some additional assumptions about a triangle, which would then allow us to compute vertices. For example, we might assume that the triangle is equilateral, and its bottom edge is horizontal. Then, if the center of the triangle is at $(a,b)$, and its circumradius is $r$, the three vertices are given by:
$$
(a,b+r) 
\quad ; \quad \big(a+ \tfrac12\sqrt3 r,\; b - \tfrac12 r  \big)
\quad ; \quad \big(a- \tfrac12\sqrt3 r,\; b - \tfrac12 r  \big)
$$

Comment: So what information would I need to determine the triangles vertices?

Comment: Please see additions to my answer